# Need to pull a report on the count of cases worked by an agent. But agent does not own the cases

Tags: reporting, dashboard, reports-api, joined-reports, einstein-analytics-dashboards

We are having a challenging scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

We have a team of agents who works on the customer service cases. But once the case is closed the ownership changes to the Manager's queue and the Agents do not have access to the closed cases. (the cases will be in the open status only for 2 hours) They wont be able to search those cases numbers too.

The business requests us to have a dashboard built for the agents where they can see the cases they worked for that month/quarter/semi-annual.

I tried using a formula field to capture the count but that dint work. I also tried using Analytics Snapshot, but that dint help either.

We also suggested that manager can send this to their team as it is not working only for the agents since its blocked for them on the profile level itself.

Could anyone please suggest a workaround for this.

Comment: Did you look at CaseTeams?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using a new custom object that I've called **Collaborator**

The **Collaborator** object has a master-detail to the **Case** and a lookup to a **User**. (pictured below)

[image]

Then I've created a process builder to create a new **Collaborator** record related to the **Case** and current Owner's **User** (pictured below)

[image]

whenever (there is a new **Case** or the Owner is changed) AND (the Status is not "closed") (pictured below)

[image]

Then, you can leverage the resulting **Case with Collaborators** report type (*make sure to allow reporting when you create the **Collaborator** object*) for your dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new field on Case object. Field should be of Lookup(User) type.
- When the ownership of the case changes to the Agent, then the value of this new field should also be set to this Agent.
- Now your Dashboard/Report should be based upon on this new field instead of the Case Owner field.